# About CCC stats in K-means Clustering in SAS EM

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm doing a K-means Clustering in SAS Enterprise Miner (SAS EM), and while I want to check how much k (clusters) is the best, the Reference Help of Cluster node there stated:

"

CCC — The cubic clustering criterion value, which is useful in determining the number of clusters in the data. CCC values that are greater than 2 or 3 indicate good clusters, values between 0 and 2 indicate potential clusters (but they should be considered with caution), and large negative values can indicate outliers. If the number of clusters is greater than one-fifth the number of observations, CCC and ERSQ are given missing values."

This is regarding the CCC in the Cluster Statistic of the Cluster Node Result.

My question is my CCC is always around 100, even though I have cleaned the data, standardize to low kurtosis and skewness,  removed outliers, checked multicollinearity, should I focus on this stats or if I can give interpretation of my cluster and segment profile then is ok?

Thankss

I have cleaned the data, standardize to low kurtosis and skewness, removed outliers, checked multicollinearity, but the CCC is still high.